# Where did Voldemort live?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Where did Voldemort live?  If he was so special, and clearly he thought so, where was "his" manor?  Did he just mooch off other people's homes or camp out hobo style all the time?

Comment: This question can be improved in a few ways: **1.** don't solicit our 'thoughts', this is a question and answers site, not a forum for discussion. **2.** Given the question's heart is interesting, you may want to remove the extraneous bits about Bella's involvement with Voldemort. **3.** Narrow this down to one subject or question, answers here can't be too 'broad'. Good luck.

Comment: Voldemort thought the whole world belonged to him, so it doesnt matter to him where he stayed. Every place is his where hes allowing others to stay

Answer (score 10):

## He does not seem to have his own house.

There is no evidence that either Lord Voldemort or Tom Riddle ever has legally owned a house at any point. Until he graduated from Hogwarts, Tom Riddle lived at the orphanage when he was not attending Hogwarts, and of course lived at Hogwarts during the school year after turning eleven. Once he graduated, he only existed a short amount of time in typical wizarding life before his disappearance, during which he worked at Borgin and Burkes.

> “He reached the seventh year of his schooling with, as you might have expected, top grades in every examination he had taken. All around him, his classmates were deciding which jobs they were to pursue once they had left Hogwarts. Nearly everybody expected spectacular things from Tom Riddle, prefect, Head Boy, winner of the Special Award for Services to the School. I know that several teachers, Professor Slughorn amongst them, suggested that he join the Ministry of Magic, offered to set up appointments, put him in touch with useful contacts. He refused all offers. The next thing the staff knew, Voldemort was working at Borgin and Burkes.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

There is no mention of Tom Riddle owning a house between his graduation and disappearance, and on a shop assistant’s salary it is unlikely he could afford one. Harry suspects he may have traveled to Albania during this time, but it is unknown if he ever lived there and if so, where he stayed.

> “So Voldemort had managed to wheedle the location of the lost diadem out of the Grey Lady. He had travelled to that far-flung forest and retrieved the diadem from its hiding place, perhaps as soon as he left Hogwarts, before he even started work at Borgin and Burkes.
>
> And wouldn’t those secluded Albanian woods have seemed an excellent refuge when, so much later, Voldemort had needed a place to lie low, undisturbed, for ten long years?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 31 (The Battle of Hogwarts)*</sup></sub>

During this time, he may have lived in an apartment, which he could easily leave behind when he disappeared. It is likely wherever he lived then would have been too accessible for him to live once he became Lord Voldemort, so it is unlikely he would be able to use it again after this time.

> “But before they were sure beyond doubt that the cup and the locket were both gone, the assistant who had worked at Borgin and Burkes, the young man who had visited Hepzibah so regularly and charmed her so well, had resigned his post and vanished. His superiors had no idea where he had gone; they were as surprised as anyone at his disappearance. And that was the last that was seen or heard of Tom Riddle for a very long time.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

Before rising to power as Lord Voldemort, he disappeared from view, during which time not much is known about what he was doing - which includes a lack of knowledge of where he lived. He would have lived somewhere secluded, or in multiple secluded locations, since he was able to keep his activities so well hidden.

> “And now for the very last recollection I have to show you, at least until you manage to retrieve Professor Slughorn’s memory for us. Ten years separate Hokey’s memory and this one, ten years during which we can only guess at what Lord Voldemort was doing …’
>
> Harry got to his feet once more as Dumbledore emptied the last memory into the Pensieve.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

During the time of his rise to power until his being ripped from his body, it is also unknown where Voldemort lived. He gained power steadily for eleven years, a quite long period, but it is not known where he lived during that time.

> “Harry had been a year old the night that Voldemort – the most powerful Dark wizard for a century, a wizard who had been gaining power steadily for eleven years – arrived at his house and killed his father and mother.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 2 (The Scar)*</sup></sub>

After being ripped from his body at the Potters’ house, Voldemort hid in an Albanian forest until Quirrell found him, and returned to it after Quirrell’s death. After meeting Wormtail, awaiting the ingredients for his restoration to a body, he lived in two known places, neither of them his. He stayed for some part of the time in the abandoned Riddle house.

> “There was a pause, and then the man called Wormtail spoke again.
>
> ‘My Lord, may I ask how long we are going to stay here?’
>
> ‘A week,’ said the cold voice. ‘Perhaps longer. The place is moderately comfortable, and the plan cannot proceed yet. It would be foolish to act before the Quidditch World Cup is over.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, he stayed in Barty Crouch Sr.’s house, to watch over him while he was under the Imperius Curse.

> “And what became of Wormtail after you attacked Moody?’ said Dumbledore.
>
> ‘Wormtail returned to care for my master, in my father’s house, and to keep watch over my father.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35 (Veritaserum)*</sup></sub>

After being restored to a body, it is unknown where Voldemort lived until he is shown living in Malfoy Manor. Though it is not known where he lived before then, it seems likely that it was *not* at Malfoy Manor, since the Malfoys only seem to be quite the level of uncomfortable as they are when sharing their home with him in the seventh book.

> “I have given you your liberty, Lucius, is that not enough for you? But I have noticed that you and your family seem less than happy of late … what is it about my presence in your home that displeases you, Lucius?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

At one point, Harry, Ron, and Hermione listed places that they knew Voldemort had lived, and they also did not know of any house he owned.

> “As Dumbledore had told Harry that he believed Voldemort had hidden the Horcruxes in places important to him, they kept reciting, in a sort of dreary litany, those locations they knew that Voldemort had lived in or visited. The orphanage where he had been born and raised, Hogwarts, where he had been educated, Borgin and Burkes, where he had worked after leaving school, then Albania, where he had spent his years of exile: these formed the basis of their speculations.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 15 (The Goblin’s Revenge)*</sup></sub>

There does not seem to be any evidence that Lord Voldemort ever legally owned a house, and for most of the time, where he lived is not known.

Comment: Now how did I know _you_ were going to be the first to answer? :-D

Comment: @Möoz Because you’re a better psychic than Trelawney? ;) Also, thanks! :D

Comment: To be fair, _everyone_ is a better psychic than Trelawney!

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that ***Tom does indeed own a house (and a manor house at that)***. Or at least did for a while. While he doesn't seem to have spent much time in the UK we know that he did visit and live in his own house for a short while.

Like any good author writing fantasy-in-reality, JKR has not divulged every least and tiniest detail about the Wizarding World and its relationship with the Muggle World. We must look elsewhere for the answer. In this case, I think a strong case can be made for this proposition if we examine

**UK Inheritance Law**

We know Tom's lineage on both sides. On his mother's side he's of the House of Gaunt, a pure blood family, and ultimately Slytherin's descendant. On his father's side, he's a Riddle, a very wealthy (if snobbish) muggle family with extensive ownership of the region in and around Little Hangleton.

We know from *Goblet of Fire* that, according to village lore, a very curious thing occurred one day at Riddle House: the three Riddles were all found dead.

> Fifty years before, at daybreak on a fine summer's morning, when the Riddle House had still been well kept and impressive, a maid had entered the drawing room to find all three Riddles dead. (...) "Lying there with their eyes wide open! Cold as ice! Still in their dinner things!"  *Goblet of Fire* ch. 1

We learn that the "three Riddles" are in fact "elderly Mr. and Mrs. Riddle" and their "grown-up son, Tom".

We further learn that Frank the gardener saw skulking about the place a "teenage boy, a stranger, dark-haired and pale". This is obviously Tom Riddle. Since the muggle police have no awareness of the Wizarding World, they have no idea how the Riddles died and medicine at the time couldn't have helped much and so the deaths, while considered odd, weren't treated as murders.

So, Tom Riddle gets off scot free, and with one to three waves of his wand inherits Riddle House

The pertinent [UK inheritance laws](https://imperiallegal.com/media/articles/inheritance-in-the-uk-how-it-works/) inform us that the child inherits from parents & grandparents. Since it's unclear who he killed first, we can't really say with certainty whether he would have inherited from his father or his grandparents.

---

Of course, there is one small problem: Riddle House has been owned by several other muggles since the deaths of the Riddle family.

I'm not lawyer enough to unravel the knot, but would suppose that, Tom being more or less alive the whole time and having access to the incredible wealth of his followers, he would at least have a good case to oust the squatters in a confundus influenced muggle court had he wanted to.

Comment: I think that Lord Voldemort so despised "The Riddles" that he would never have set foot into that house-ever-except to kill them!  And he would never return either-his hate was profound.  And since he was a very knowledgeable wizard he could probably create a safe temporary haven in a pinch with a little magic.

Comment: @CorinneAdams - True he hated muggles, and despised his muggle father most of all. And yet, he did return to his ancestral manse and remained there for a while.  In any event, his hatreds and personal ickiness don't really have a bearing on the legalities

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mal's answer, between Voldemort's resignation from Borgin and Burkes and his application to be the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher at Hogwarts there is a period of about ten years. Dumbledore has some knowledge of his whereabouts and activities, but his knowledge is far from complete.

At the time of his application, he had already done extensive experimentation in the Dark Arts, and at this point was no longer the handsome young man that he was before (as is related in *Half-Blood Prince*).

It is reasonable to suppose that he traveled extensively during this period—doubtlessly visiting communities where the Dark Arts were practiced—and thus had no residence *per se*.